# Where to define props to access them in my React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Unfortunately, I could not able to solve the problem, which I am facing to develop the `to do list` application. May I ask please what is the problem in the folliwing code?

```
function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert('Moin');
    props.addTask("Say hello!");
}

function Form(props){
    return(
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
            <h2 className="label-wrapper">
                <label htmlFor="new-todo-input" className="label__lg">
                    What needs to be done?
    ...
```

**following error comes**

Failed to compile.

./src/components/Form.js
Line 8:  'props' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: u need to pass props on `function form(props)` ?

Comment: handleSubmit is outside the Form function. It has no clue about the props. Place handleSubmit inside Form function or pass props as a parameter and then access props as you do.

Answer (score 5):

```
function Form(props){

  function handleSubmit(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //alert('Moin');
      props.addTask("Say hello!");
  }

    return(
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
            <h2 className="label-wrapper">
                <label htmlFor="new-todo-input" className="label__lg">
                    What needs to be done?
```

This is to do with the **scope** of the variables, which you can read more about [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: To expand on this answer - you're trying to use your props outside the scope of your component.  This is not a React issue, but a javascript issue - you can never use a variable outside of the scope of where it was defined - in this case the function that is used to generate the component.